# Не работает wp_reset_query в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
            <?php 
                query_posts('cat=rand&p=rand');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?> 

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title post-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                    </header>

                    <div class="entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-## здесь можно вставить noindex -->

                <meta itemprop="author" content="<?php the_author() ?>"/>
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php the_time('c') ?>"/>
                <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="<?php the_permalink() ?>" content="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="<?php the_modified_time('Y-m-d')?>">

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Не понимаю почему не работает wp_reset_query, есть у кого нибудь идеи?

Comment: Напишите, в чем это выражается. "Не работает" - самое худшее описание проблемы из возможных.

Comment: Здраствуйте. А где Вы используете данный код в шаблоне? В сайдбаре, в шаблоне страниц/постов?

Comment: Andrii Golovko, Да использую в шаблоне страниц/постов, мне нужно туда подгрузить такой же пост с помощью ajax.